# Special Filtering/Grouping of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to group a pandas Dataframe by 2 columns, then another column based on the most recent date and finishing by summing the values in another column.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
     CODE     BILL_NUM   AMOUNT    DATE
1    1232      320220      $5    01/16/20 
2    1232      320320      $5    01/19/20
3    1232      320220     -$1    01/20/20
4    1216      160120      $4    01/04/20
5    1216      160120      $4    02/07/20
6    1216      160220      $2    02/08/20
7    1216      160120     -$3    02/19/20
```

After the desired grouping/filtering would return:

```
     CODE     BILL_NUM   AMOUNT    DATE
1    1232      320220      $4    01/20/20 
2    1232      320320      $5    01/19/20
3    1216      160120      $5    02/19/20
4    1216      160220      $2    02/08/20
```

Answer (score 0):

My generated dataframe; df1

[image]

Drop $, brackets and introduce - in AMOUNT column

```
df1['AMOUNT'] = df1['AMOUNT'].str.replace('(', '-')
df1['AMOUNT'] = df1['AMOUNT'].str.replace(')', '')
df1['AMOUNT'] = df1['AMOUNT'].str.replace('$', '')
df1['AMOUNT'] = df1['AMOUNT'].astype(int)
df1
```

Coerce DATE to datetime

```
df1['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])
```

Groupby and aggregate on multiple columns

```
df1.groupby(['CODE','BILL_NUM']).agg({'DATE':'max','AMOUNT':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Output

[image]